# how to create AppleScript app to run a set of terminal commands

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

How would I go about creating an AppleScript command that when I just run the script (or double click it in Finder?), it would run a set of terminal commands? The set of commands completely remove MySQL, and it has become a pain to constantly write them out. The commands are:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm /etc/my.cnf
```

There is also another command `sudo nano /etc/hostconfig` that opens a file and I need to delete a line from the file, but that seems like it'd be too hard to code, so I guess I can do that by hand. But it would be a huge help to do this automatically with a single script.

Would it just be a bunch of these commands?

```
do shell script (...)
```

Thanks,
Hristo

Comment: To change/add/remove a few lines in a text file, you could use the `sed(1)` command, which is serial editor.  Works great with regular expressions to find the line you want to remove or change, or insert a new line before or after.  See the man page or some videos on YTube.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you would use `do shell script`.

However, for the commands where you execute as super user (`sudo`) you would instead use `with administrator privileges`. So, for `sudo rm /usr/local/mysql` you'd do:

```
do shell script "rm /usr/local/mysql" with administrator privileges
```

If your list of commands is long, then it might just be easier to put all your commands into a single shell script file, and then execute that shell script using `do shell script`:

```
do shell script "/path/to/shell/script" with administrator privileges
```

Comment: when I do `do shell script "rm /usr/local/mysql" with administrator privileges`, it gives me an error and tells me that `/usr/local/mysql` is a directory. That is actually a symbolic link to a different directory... what is the problem?

Comment: try `rm -rf /usr/local/mysql`

Answer (score 17):

You don't actually need to use AppleScript for this - just put all the shell commands in a text file and give it a `.command` suffix and make sure it's executable (e.g. `chmod +x my_script.command`) - this will make it double-clickable in the Finder.

Comment: The `.command` suffix isn't quite enough -- you also have to include a shebang (i.e. add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of the text file) and add execute permission to the file (i.e. run `chmod +x /path/to/file.command`).  BTW, the big advantage of using this vs. an AppleScript is that it runs in Terminal, so you can actually interact with the script (very important if you want to use e.g. `nano` to edit a file).

Comment: @Gordon: yes, good point, I should have said that it needs to be an executable shell script with a shebang line.

Comment: note, though, that when using `sudo` in a .command you'll still have to enter your password.  if you want the script to just run on its own, this link has some good tips on how to do that: http://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-a-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password

Answer (score 0):

I find that .scpt files work best but this is just a preference thing.

Open "Script Editor" and add the following command:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql; sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*; sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM; sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*; sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*; sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*; sudo rm /etc/my.cnf; say job completed successfully" with administrator privileges
```