# Can I convert a command line script into a AppleScript?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, applescript

I have command in Terminal that I would like to put into an AppleScript file. Is this possible?

**More info**:
I'm using the following code to show hidden files. I type this on the command line in Terminal to make it work:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true
killAll Finder
```

I would like to convert this into an AppleScript file so I can double click on it and it will run sortof like a batch file in Windows.

**UPDATE**:
If there is a better option to use than a AppleScript file I would need to know how to run it from the command line in addition to double-clicking it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create AppleScript app to run a set of terminal commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154535/how-to-create-applescript-app-to-run-a-set-of-terminal-commands)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to put it in an AppleScript:

```
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true"
do shell script "killall Finder"
```

..but note that this will not be as easy to execute from the command line as a shell script would be (see @Paul R's answer).

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I might need to go this route depending on the situation.

Answer (score 5):

Although it's quite easy to do, you don't need to convert this to AppleScript - just put the commands into a text file and save it on your Desktop as e.g. `my_script.command` (the `.command` suffix is the important part). Then make sure the file is executable:

```
$ chmod +x ~/Desktop/my_script.command
```

You now have a double-clickable executable script on your desktop.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I see. If it is not a scpt file then I also need to know is it possible to run this command from the command line?

Comment: Yes, you can just run `my_script.command` from the command line. It's just a shell script with a special name that the Finder recognises but you can run it like you would any other shell script.

Comment: OK. How would you run any other shell script? Like sh my_script.sh?  I would rename my_script.command to my_script.sh? I was planning for AppleScript but this could work well if its the same.

Comment: You just invoke it by name, e.g. at the bash prompt: `~/Desktop/my_script.command`, assuming you've saved it on the desktop.