# Can Python program using PyQt be scriptable and controlled by AppleScript?

Tags: python, pyqt, applescript

I have a Python-based GUI application that uses PyQt. Is there any way to make it scriptable on Mac OSX, such that I can control it through AppleScript?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. AppleScript can execute shell programs just fine. In this case, you'd want something like:

```
do shell script "python <yourscript>.py"
```

Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154535/how-to-create-applescript-app-to-run-a-set-of-terminal-commands) for more information on running shell scripts from within AppleScript.

If this doesn't solve your problem because of some problem with interfacing PyQt, let us know.

Comment: This solves the problem of executed the entire application. My question was rather on writing PyQt app, and then adding information such that I can control every of its aspect by AppleScript. Say, open and close windows, open files, execute functions and so on.